# How can I give my application a transparent title bar and menu, like Firefox

Tags: c#, winforms

How can i make title bar and menu bar same like in my windows application like this?

[image]

Comment: come on guys, this isn't that bad a question. There may be hundreds of people wanting to learn how to do that.

Comment: It's not a bad question, but the original title was totally vague, and the answer already exists on the site, and the author appears not to have made any effort to try to answer it himself before posting.

Comment: Do you want to have the same glass look like the link that Raymond Chen posted?

Comment: Try checking [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2006/04/18/578637.aspx) out.

Comment: I got it from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163435.aspx